# Passing expression to handlebars custom helper

Tags: handlebars.js

New to handlebars, I've registered a helper and I can´t figure out what seems to be a simple task: how to pass an expression to handlebars helper.

Let's say:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('or', function (v1, v2) {
  return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
}
```

And when using it:

```
{{#conditional @index this.warranty_id !== "DEFAULT_FACTORY" }}
```

Of course it fails, and I can't figure out how make it work. What I need is that the expression being passed returns a boolean to be the v2 value inside the helper.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of ember are you on? You should be using [Ember.Helper.helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html#method_helper)

Comment: @Kitler thanks for your answer, no ember, handlebars node module.

Comment: @Guillermo: There isnt any `!==` in handlebars out of the box. You need to write a custom helper for the same as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a `helper` to check for `!==` and then nest it as a subexpression inside your `or` helper.

`OR` helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('or', function (v1, v2) {
  return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
}
```

`!==` helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ne', function (v1, v2) {
  return (v1 !== v2); 
}
```

and then in your template:

```
{{#or @index (ne this.warranty_id "DEFAULT_FACTORY")}}
```